# Passing data from chrome extension to standalone ReactApp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have created extension using plain javascript, now i want to pass data from extension to react-app stand alone,extension pop-up, a button is shown, user clicks on button and captures screenshot , now i want to send this screenshot to my separate reactapp which is running on localhost, i am unable to connect my extensions script with react component , is it possible?

```
background.js:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === "captureScreenshot") {
    captureScreenshot(sendResponse);
    return true; // Indicates that we'll respond asynchronously
  }
});

function captureScreenshot(callback) {
  console.log("Capturing screenshot...");
  // Capture the screenshot here and return the data URL
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
    { format: "png" }, // Adjust format as needed
    function (screenshotDataUrl) {
      console.log("Screenshot captured:", screenshotDataUrl);
      callback(screenshotDataUrl);
    }
  );
}


Content.js

const screenshotUrl = "data:image/png;base64,ABC..."; 
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "sendScreenshot", screenshotUrl });


Manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Dopplio Chrome Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A simple Chrome extension built with React",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {}
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "scripting",
      "storage"
    ],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "icons": {},
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
      "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": [
          "http://localhost:8000/*"
        ]
      }
      
}

React Component:

 useEffect(() => {
        console.log('hello')
        window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
            if (event.source === window && event.data.action === "sendScreenshot") {
              // Handle the received screenshot data
              const screenshotUrl = event.data.screenshotUrl;
              console.log("Received screenshot URL:", screenshotUrl);
      
            }
          });
 
      
          // Clean up event listener if needed when the component unmounts
          return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("message");
          };
      }, []); //
```

I am working first am I using this correct approach, if this wrong then how i can create an extension which can intereact with react app, do i have to send data from extension to server then get data from server to react?
Please suggest i am stuck for so long.Note web extension scripts and react app are separate.